# Image_tag in options_for_select in rails

Tags: ruby

This is my code

```
<td> <%= select_tag "options", options_for_select( [["Show",
"/registrars/"+registrar.id.to_s],["Edit", "/edit_registrars/"+registrar.id.to_s],
["Dashboard", "/homes/"+registrar.enrollment_application.id.to_s], **
[image_tag("file_cabinet.png"), "/registrars/"+registrar.id.to_s]**, ] ) %></td>
```

I want to use this

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("file_cabinet.png", :border=>0), :action => :show, :id => 
registrar, :filecabinet => true) %>
```

In above code if you see I tried but it is not working , any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest an image tag inside an option tag.